# ia32lib installing Ubuntu studio

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, installation

my ubuntu studio is a 64 bit system and i have installed Eclipse IDE it was working correctly for java development but not working for android I thought that might me ia32 library missing so trying to insalling giving me "no pakcage avaliable" any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s called “ia32-libs” (that’s what it’s called on my Debian Unstable system, should be the same on Ubuntu). Tip: try

```
apt-cache search ia32
```

to search for likely package names.